# How to apply a constant function to a vector of values?

Tags: functions

I have a list of functions

```
func[x_]={1,Cos[x],Sin[x]}
```

(for example) and I want to apply each function to a list of values

```
xval={a,b,c,d}
```

obtaining a list of tuples.  The problem is that the constant function will not evaluate to a tuple (it will remain as a scalar)

```
func[xval] = {1, {0, -1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1, 0}}
```

Is there a way to force the creation of a tuple (with the function value) of the same size as `xval`, if I don't know what are the functions in `func` (if there is or not a constant function in it)?

Comment: You can use pure functions: `funcs  = {# , Cos[#] , Sin[#] }&`

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Won't that give `x` in the first component, not a list of copies of the constant?

Comment: @MichaelE2, sorry, I changed it and forgot to change it back again :p The correct thing is `funcs = {1 + 0 # , Cos[#] , Sin[#] }&`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Or just `1&` (`{1, Cos@#, Sin@#}&`).

Comment: you could also add one more definition to your function: `func[t:{__}]:=func/@t`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why it works with `Cos` and `Sin` is that those functions are `Listable`. So just make a constant function that is Listable, too:

```
func[x_]:={Function[y, 1, Listable][x],Cos[x],Sin[x]}
xval={a, b, c, d}
func[xval]
(*
==> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {Cos[a], Cos[b], Cos[c], Cos[d]},
     {Sin[a], Sin[b], Sin[c], Sin[d]}}
*)
```

Note that here it is important that you use `:=` to define `func`, otherwise it gets evaluated already at definition time, resulting in a single `1` again.

If you need it often, you can define a function to generate a listable constant function:

```
const[x_] := Function[y, x, Listable]
```

Then you can write:

```
func2[x_] := { const[1][x], Cos[x], Sin[x] }
func2[xval]
(*
==> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {Cos[a], Cos[b], Cos[c], Cos[d]}, 
     {Sin[a], Sin[b], Sin[c], Sin[d]}}
*)
```

Comment: I really liked the simplicity of your answer, and the function definition `const[x_]` you showed. It works very well (and solves @Mr.Wizard's  problem with `List`s inside the argument list).  Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

First: you should probably be defining `func` using [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) rather than [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html).

The behavior you want is closely related to the concept of [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) functions in *Mathematica.*  It is this [*attribute*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Attributes.html) that makes `Sin` and `Cos` behave as you observe.  If you add the `Listable` attribute to `func` either directly (using [`SetAttribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAttribute.html), i.e. `SetAttribute[func, Listable]`) or by way of a container [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) you get this:

```
f2 = Function[xx, func[xx], Listable];

f2[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {{1, Cos[a], Sin[a]},
>  {1, Cos[b], Sin[b]},
>  {1, Cos[c], Sin[c]},
>  {1, Cos[d], Sin[d]}}
> ```

You may [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) this output to achieve the form you desire:

```
f2[{a, b, c, d}]\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 1},
>  {Cos[a], Cos[b], Cos[c], Cos[d]},
>  {Sin[a], Sin[b], Sin[c], Sin[d]}}
> ```

Another approach may be to Map the function over the list manually, then transpose:

```
Map[func, {a, b, c, d}]\[Transpose]    (* same output as above *)
```

---

#### A more targeted approach

Reconsidering this problem perhaps what you want can be attained with post-processing the existing output of `func`.  I tried to keep the method above as general as possible, however since you did specify "a vector of values" rather than an arbitrary [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html)-based structure there is a simpler method using [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html).  Consider the behavior:

```
Thread[{1, {a, b, c, d}}]
```

> ```
> {{1, a}, {1, b}, {1, c}, {1, d}}
> ```

This allows us:

```
func[{a, b, c, d}] // Thread // Transpose
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 1},
>  {Cos[a], Cos[b], Cos[c], Cos[d]},
>  {Sin[a], Sin[b], Sin[c], Sin[d]}}
> ```

Caveat: if the constant term in the original function is itself a `List` this fails:

```
func2[x_] := {{1}, Cos[x], Sin[x]};

func2[{a, b, c, d}] // Thread // Transpose
```

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {{1},{Cos[a],Cos[b],Cos[c],Cos[d]},{Sin[a],Sin[b],Sin[c],Sin[d]}} cannot be combined. >>

Answer (score 4):

You can `Map` the function over the list and Transpose the result:

```
func[x_] := {1,Cos[x],Sin[x]};
xval = {a, b, c, d};
Transpose[func /@ xval]
```

Result:

```
{
  {1, 1, 1, 1}, {Cos[a], Cos[b], Cos[c], Cos[d]},
  {Sin[a], Sin[b], Sin[c], Sin[d]}
}
```

You can even overload the function if you want it to do this on any list automatically:

```
func[x : Except[_List]] := {1,Cos[x],Sin[x]};
func[list_List] := Transpose[func /@ list];
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been interested in a vectorized constant function that, like built-in mathematical functions, evaluates packed arrays to packed arrays.  Here's a way, but you have to manually implement listability for non-packed arrays and other lists.

```
constFN[k_][x_?ArrayQ] := ConstantArray[k, Dimensions[x]];
constFN[k_][x_List] := constFN[k] /@ x;
constFN[k_][x_?NumericQ] := k;
```

Examples:

```
constFN[2][{2, 3, {4}}]                (* listability *)
(*  {2, 2, {2}}  *)

constFN[2.][E]
(*  2.  *)

constFN[2.][x]                         (* produces a packed array *)
% /. x -> RandomReal[1, {2, 3}]
% // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*
  constFN[2.][x]
  {{2., 2., 2.}, {2., 2., 2.}}
  True
*)

ifn = Interpolation@ Table[{{t}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}, {t, 0., 2., 1./128}];
constFN[Tan[x]][ifn[x]] /. x -> Pi/6   (* constant symbolic expression *)
(* {1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3]}  *)

constFN[Range[4]][x]                   (* multiples of a vector constant *)
% /. x -> RandomReal[1, 3]
% // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*
  constFN[{1, 2, 3, 4}][x]
  {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
  True
*)
```

*Notes:* Using `Listable` unpacks packed arrays, which is why I did it manually.

```
ClearAll[fUP];
SetAttributes[fUP, Listable];
fUP[k_, x_] := k;

On["Packing"];
fUP[2., RandomReal[1, 3]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
Off["Packing"]
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to HoldForm.
>
> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack: Unpacking array with dimensions {3} in call to fUP.

```
(*  False  *)
```

Note also that `constFN[]` replaces the packed arrays in any sort of (nested) list of packed arrays with constant packed arrays.  One could also use `SparseArray` instead of packed arrays. `Normal` converts these to packed arrays when `k` is a machine `Integer` or `Real`. Just replace the `ConstantArray` definition with the following:

```
constFN[k_][x_?ArrayQ] := SparseArray[{}, Dimensions[x], k];
```

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
Through[{1 & /@ # &, Cos, Sin}@xval]
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {Cos[a], Cos[b], Cos[c], Cos[d]}, {Sin[a], Sin[b], Sin[c], Sin[d]}}

Or, if `func[x_]:={1, Cos[x],Sin[x]}` is already defined,

```
Through[(Function[y, #, Listable] & /@ func[y])@xval]
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {Cos[a], Cos[b], Cos[c], Cos[d]}, {Sin[a], Sin[b], 
>     Sin[c], Sin[d]}}

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ConstantArray`, but you have to specify your variable.

```
Clear[func2]

func2[x_List] := {ConstantArray[1, Length[x]], Cos[x], Sin[x]}
func2[x_] := {1, Cos[x], Sin[x]}

func2[xval]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {Cos[a], Cos[b], Cos[c], Cos[d]}, {Sin[a], Sin[b], Sin[c], Sin[d]}} *)

func2[a]
(* {1, Cos[a], Sin[a]} *)
```

There is also a way to do it with pure functions:

```
funcP := {1 + #*0, Cos[#], Sin[#]} &
```

You have to add 0 to your constant. I dont know if this is the best way to do this, but maybe these two approaches will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Query`

```
func = {1 &, Cos, Sin};
xval = {a, b, c, d};

Query[Transpose, func] @ xval
```

gives

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1},
 {Cos[a], Cos[b], Cos[c], Cos[d]},
 {Sin[a], Sin[b], Sin[c], Sin[d]}}
```