# Apply matrix of function to a list and get matrix of lists

Tags: functions, matrix, list-manipulation

Say I have table in the shape of a matrix of the form:

```
f[x_] = {{1, 1/4 + x/4}, {0, 1/4 + x/4}}
```

and a list of numbers

```
list = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

What is the easiest way to get a matrix of the same shape as above with its elements corresponding to the each function element of `f[x_]` applied to the `list`?

The trouble here is that `f[x_]` involves constant functions so that doing `f[list]` gives:

```
In[188]:= f[list]
Out[188]= {{1,{1/2,3/4,1,5/4,3/2}},{0,{1/2,3/4,1,5/4,3/2}}}
```

(only the non constant elements are evaluated).

On the other hand, doing, `f /@ list` evaluates `f[x_]` as a matrix valued function and gives a list of 2 by 2 matrices:

```
 In[189]:= f/@list
 Out[189]= {{{1,1/2},{0,1/2}},{{1,3/4},{0,3/4}},{{1,1},{0,1}},{{1,5/4},{0,5/4}},{{1,3/2},{0,3/2}}}
```

This is not what I want either.

What I want is

```
{{{1,1,1,1,1},{1/2,3/4,1,5/4,3/2}},{{0,0,0,0,0},{1/2,3/4,1,5/4,3/2}}}
```

Comment: good point. Just edited.

Comment: `{{1+0 x, 1/4 + x/4}, {0 x, 1/4 + x/4}}`?

Comment: @Kuba Only if you use `SetDelayed`

Comment: After a review of the answers to [(129755)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129755/121) I have concluded that this question "already has an answer" there, and I have marked it accordingly.  My favorite solution is bienti's:  `f[x_] := {{1 + 0 x, 1/4 + x/4}, {0 x, 1/4 + x/4}}`

Comment: I had seen and tested the mentioned other solutions before asking my question. These are not applicable here as these only work for one dimensional arrays.

Comment: In addition, the function f[x_] is defined programmatically in my case and I am not at leisure to use the aforementioned trick mentioned by @Mr.Wizard quoting bienti. The answer below is the one I was looking for.

Comment: @jrekier would you please edit your question to explain this?

Comment: @jrekier In my answer I give `func[{a, b, c, d}] // Thread // Transpose` as a solution.  For your example `Transpose /@ Thread /@ f[list]` will work.  Are these programmatically defined functions always the same shape (or at least depth) or do you need something more general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_] = {{1, 1/4 + x/4}, {0, 1/4 + x/4}};
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Then

```
Transpose /@ Transpose[f /@ list, {2, 1}]
```

> {{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1/2, 3/4, 1, 5/4, 3/2}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 
>      3/4, 1, 5/4, 3/2}}}

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.